# Showing clipped header text

Tags: html, css, hover, overflow

Is it possible to fully show clipped (`overflow: hidden`) text on hover, so that it's readable. A rule like

```
div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

leads to the text shown over another one, so that nothing can be read.

That's hard to explain, but easy to see: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xGOgjzO8HjcZ3hHFrueF?p=preview). Changing sizes is not an option. A tooltip would surely work, but I find it rather intrusive.

A side question: How can I tell if a given div content is fully shown or clipped?

Comment: adding `height: auto;
    word-break: break-word;` on `div: hover` works for you?

Comment: @kukkuz [Rather not](https://plnkr.co/edit/ah4rU7G0uT3pbBPbrsKP?p=preview) as the real table is rather big and everything moves and this is rather disturbing,

Answer (score 0):

If it possible you can try change you style like this

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```